# Передать Guid в WCF сервис с сериализацие NetDataContractSerializer

Tags: .net, wcf

Есть такой контракт

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [NetDataContract]
    void PassGuid(Guid id);

    [OperationContract]
    [NetDataContract]
    void PassInt(int id);
}
```

Описание атрибута `NetDataContractAttribute` [тут](https://yoursrp.wordpress.com/2009/07/06/netdatacontractattribute).
При попытке вызвать `PassGuid` получаем ошибку:

```
Additional information: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: 
There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:id. 
The InnerException message was 'XML 'Element' 'http://tempuri.org/:id' does not contain expected attribute 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/:Type'. 
The deserializer has no knowledge of which type to deserialize. 
Check that the type being serialized has the same contract as the type being deserialized.'.  
Please see InnerException for more details.
```

Хотя метод `PassInt` вызывается без проблем.

Полный исходный код [тут](https://github.com/bonza/WcfNetDataContract).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том что в контракте который генерируется на стороне клиента (см. файл `WcfClient\Service References\TestService\Reference.cs`) отсутствуют атрибуты `[NetDataContract]`.

Поэтому на стороне клиента в качестве сериализатора работает `DataContractSerializer`.

Чтобы работало и на клиенте и на сервере я бы рекомендовал контракт (`ITestService` и атрибут `NetDataContractAttribute`) выделить в отдельную сборку и сослаться на нее из клиента и из сервера. Кроме этого придется отказаться от автоматически созданного proxy и создавать его самому наследуясь от `ClientBase<ITestService>` либо напрямую через `ChannelFactory<ITestService>`.

Comment: Т.е. или отказаться от этого сериализатора, или отказаться от автогенерации прокси классов?

Comment: Да, именно так. Сериализатор добавляется путем указания специфического атрибута, реализующего `IOperationBehavior`. Через WSDL невозможно передать такой атрибут (код атрибута-то надо откуда-то брать). Поэтому либо используете свою DLL с контактом (и кодом атрибута внутри) и тогда можно использовать этот сериализатор, либо не использовать собственные атрибуты но тогда сериализатор стандартный.